# PHP Logout And Session Issues

Tags: php, session

Hers is my *logout script* on `logout.php`:

```
unset($_SESSION['user']['id']);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="login.php"</script>';
```

My problem is after logout when I click on browser back button I got redirect back to `index.php` page. The `index.php` shown for a while and after that it get redirected to `login.php`. I don't understand why it redirect to back to `index.php` page. I don't want to show any page / content to a user even for a second after it gets logged out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `unset($_SESSION['user']['id']);` and `session_unset();`. `session_destroy()` will do it all. Try with -

```
session_destroy();
header('location:logout.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

check condition on every page after login

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['user'] && !isset($_SESSION['user']['id'])){ 
    header('location:login.php') ;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your user is going to have to load that page with the javascript, and the javascript is doing the redirection. What you want is to issue a header in PHP to force the redirect immediately. However if you've already put a header out, you can't do it again, so you need to include another PHP file with the output you want to display, and then die(). Doing it through Javascript there will always be a pageload before the window.location() call takes effect, and many people with popup blockers might not even follow the javascript redirect properly.

Answer (score 0):

try to use.

```
 header ("Location: login.php");
```